# How to Parsing Full String and split into several String in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, text-parsing, string-parsing, vba

I need help in Excel VBA. I have situation that i need to split into several data from a String. There is now specific delimiter, the condition is only a Keyword.

The example of the Full String Data i got is like this:

```
/*ORDER FORM*/
Name: Randy
Full Address: Unknown Street 123 ABC
Phone:0246854612
Order: 1x G Action Figure
1x Y Action Figure
2x Z Action Figure

/*Fill Bank and Amount of Transfer*/
Bank: ABC
Total: 2000

/*If you Reseller, Fill Data below*/
Sender:
SenderPhone:

/*Thank you for your Order*/
```

And, From That data i need to send several Data into Several Cell or Variables. For examples, if i want to get this:

```
var Name = "Randy"

var address = "Unknown Street 123 ABC"

var phone = "0246854612" {Text format}

var Bank = "ABC"

var amount = 2000

var item1 = "G Action Figure"

var qty1 = 1 {from 1x G Action Figure}

var item2 = "Y Action Figure"

var qty2 = 1

var item3 = "Z Action Figure"

var qty3 = 2
```

How can i Achieve this.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Does the data always appear in the same order and are there always the same number of rows? You could split the whole string using a carriage return.

```
MySplit = Split(MyString,VbCrLf)
```

And then assigning each part of the array to a variable.

```
Name = MySplit(0)
Address = MySplit(1)
Phone = MySplit(2)
'...etc...
```

Comment: Sometimes its not in same order. Thank you for your quick help. I'll try that method.

Comment: If that's the case you could use a CASE statement on the left part of the string up until the : to check which variable to assign each part of the array to.

Comment: Thank you So Much Jason, I'll Try CASE immediately