# Excel+VBA: Userfrom string Deal(Order) Number parsing

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a full function report file which connects to old version access data base. I need to build a Userform where user can enter deal (order) number just like we can add pages in print dialog box.

So far I have found below question which has given me partial answer:
[How to Parsing Full String and split into several String in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787492/how-to-parsing-full-string-and-split-into-several-string-in-excel-vba)

I can use Split(string) method to get various deal numbers when separated by ",".

However, I also need From to TO deal number option as well.

so, if user enters on String1 = "10001 - 10050, 20111 , 20115"

then I need output as

Deal_Line.Deal_Number >= 10001 and Deal_Line.Deal_Number <= 10050
and Deal_Line.Deal_Number = 20111 and Deal_Line.Deal_Number = 20115.

I can refine SQL String for my requirement, I would like to know if there is a way to use two deliminator.

Comment: split again by "-" and see if the array has results, so `split(split(string1,",")(0),"-")`  or even, a bit brutal, but something along these lines `sql="Deal_Line.Deal_Number >=" & replace(split(string1,",")(0) ,"-","and Deal_Line.Deal_Number <= ")`

Comment: ...or just do the replace on the input string, `replace(strInput,"-","and Deal_Line.Deal_Number <= ")` then split by comma and append the prefix `Deal_Line.Deal_Number >="` when constructing the SQL if the segment contains `and deal_line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @user3598756 answer, (which does exactly what you asked for) and interpreting your requirements I come up with the following:

```
Function ProcessString(strng1 As String, fieldname As String) As String
    Dim sqlStrng As String
    Dim strng As Variant, limits As Variant

    For Each strng In Split(strng1, ",")
        limits = Split(strng, "-")
        If UBound(limits) = 0 Then
            sqlStrng = sqlStrng & "[FIELD] = " & limits(0) & "|"
        Else
            sqlStrng = sqlStrng & "([FIELD] >= " & Trim(limits(0)) & " And [FIELD] <= " & Trim(limits(1)) & ")|"
        End If
    Next
    ProcessString = Replace(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Join(Split(Left(sqlStrng, Len(sqlStrng) - 1), "|"), " Or ")), "[FIELD]", fieldname)
End Function
```

The test line would be:

```
MsgBox ProcessString("10001 - 10050, 20111 , 20115","Deal_Line.Deal_Number")
```

This will produce an output that I think is more likely to be what you actually want - using `OR` instead of `AND` for starters, adding in parentheses needed for the `OR` to work properly and allowing for multiple table/field names.
Then again, maybe I've misinterpreted your requirement - I just can't see what use having all `AND` would be one one field.

Comment: Thank you @CLR
You are right I need to use Or instead of And.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this *helper* function:

```
Function ProcessString(strng1 As String) As String
    Dim sqlStrng As String
    Dim strng As Variant, limits As Variant

    For Each strng In Split(strng1, ",")
        limits = Split(strng, "-")
        If UBound(limits) = 0 Then
            sqlStrng = sqlStrng & "Deal_Line.Deal_Number = " & limits(0) & "|"
        Else
            sqlStrng = sqlStrng & "Deal_Line.Deal_Number >= " & limits(0) & " And Deal_Line.Deal_Number <= " & limits(1) & "|"
        End If
    Next
    ProcessString = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Join(Split(Left(sqlStrng, Len(sqlStrng) - 1), "|"), " And "))
End Function
```

to be tested/expolited in your "main" code as:

```
Sub main()

    MsgBox ProcessString("10001 - 10050, 20111 , 20115")

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a small question to learn something: Why do you use join(split(..)) instead of replace?

Comment: Because it'd be too easy and wouldn't allow to show people how mant things I know! Good point, I can't test it at the moment but I'm not seeing anything against Replace usage

Comment: You are welcome. But i'd like to make it clear things are not the way they should be: 1) my answer was the first to solve your question as you asked for originally 2) @CLR came after and took it thoroughly to change the very last part to follow a right inspiration about your possible needs - he should have made it a comment to my answer 3) the final outcome would be you accepting my answer.